# Subroutine to Display the QMODEL Serial in CLLE

Tags: ibm-midrange, subroutine, rpgle, control-language

I need to make a CLLE program in IBM RDi that will allow the user to enter options 1 to 7 which will call a subroutine to be run. I can't figure out how to have the System Serial/Model Number displayed when they enter 5. This is the code I have so far relating to option 5.

```
DCL        &SERIAL *CHAR (10)

WHEN       (&OPTION = '5' *OR &OPTION = '05') CALLSUBR OPTION5

SUBR       OPTION5
           RTVSYSVAL  SYSVAL(QMODEL) RTNVAR(&SERIAL)
           CHGVAR     &MSGTXT ('SYSTEM SERIAL #: ' *BCAT &SERIAL)
ENDSUBR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close!  QMODEL is the system value for the machine model.  What you want is [QSRLNBR](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzakz/rzakzsystemoverview.htm?lang=en).